# different assets for Front end and admin dashboard in Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am creating an application that will have a front end and an admin dashboard. The front end assets and the admin assets are different but there's only one index.html.
How can I conditionally load the assets (js & css) for both front end and admin dashboard?